# File compiles successfully but changes don't get reflected in console

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I'm trying to make changes inside of a .js file that of which compiles successfully according to `npm run watch` outputs.  The change I made is inside of a `console.log();` statement just to test out if my changes get reflected.  I've tried `cmd + shift + r` because I thought it could've been cached but it seems that's not the case.  What could be a reason why?  I've tried running `npm run dev` as well but to no avail.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

1. try to restart your server
2. if a restart does not work then

   php artisan cache:clear

   php artisan config:clear

Comment: yeah I tried that already... but it's still won't reflect changes.  This is so confusing :(.

Comment: give me the full path of your .js file location